# Which formula I can use to match two text in cell result in pass or fail

Tags: excel, if-statement, match

I have text in two cells, I am aiming, if both text are the same in the cell, result in pass.

If the text is different then result in Fail.

Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 0):

```
=if(A1=B1,"pass","fail")
```

But you might need to consider the quality of the data - leading or trailing spaces will cause false fails.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this formula as well, however you may need to consider the leading or trailing spaces, as well as also non printable characters which depends only upon the source of your data you are using.

Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=IF(EXACT(A1,B1),"Pass","Fail")
```

[image: EXACT_FORMULA]